# Toad is not connected to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have installed Oracle 11g database and Toad on my laptop, SQL*Plus is connected to write queries but Toad is not going to connect. It shows error "You have no Oracle Clients installed".

Comment: You need to have Oracle 11g Client software to be installed in order to connect from Toad

Comment: If you are on 64-bit Windows, check that Toad and Oracle are either both 32-bit or both 64-bit. You cannot mix 32 & 64.